# A proper chain complex is exact iff its homology complex is trivial

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

All chain complexes are in a category $\mathcal{C}$, pointed, regular, cocomplete. If these hypothesys are not sufficient to answer the question, please add further conditions on $\mathcal{C}$. The only condition on $\mathcal{C}$ I don't want to use is $\mathcal{C}$ additive.

**Definition 1** We say that a chain complex $(C,d)$ is exact in degree $n$ when the factorisation $\bar{d}_{n+1}:C_{n+1}\to\operatorname{ker}(d_n)$ of $d_{n+1}$ over the kernel of $d_n$ is a cokernel. The complex $C$ is exact when it is exact in all degrees.

**Definiiton 2** A chain complex $(C,d)$ is proper when $d$ factors as a cokernel $e$ followed by a kernel $m$.

Obviously, every exact complex is proper.

**Definition 3** Given a chain complex $(C,d)$ and $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, the $n$-th homology object $H_nC$ is the cokernel of $\bar{d}_{n+1}:C_{n+1}\to \operatorname{ker}(d_n)$. All homology objects together form a chain complex $(HC,0)$ with zero differentials.

**Proposition** A proper chain complex $(C,d)$ is exact if and only if $HC=0$.

**proof** Let $(C,d)$ be a proper chain complex.

Suppose $(C,d)$ is exact. Then $\bar{d}$ is a cokernel, hence an epimorphism, hence its kernel is the zero morphism.

Viceversa, suppose $HC=0$. Then $\bar{d}$ is an epimorphism. How do I prove that $\bar{d}$ is actually a cokernel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I was wrong. The condition that the complex is proper is actually sufficient to prove the result in your setting.

Since $(C,d)$ is proper, $d_{n+1}$ factors as a cokernel $e$ followed by a kernel $m$. Now
$$d_nme=d_nd_{n+1}=0=0e$$
implies that $d_nm=0$, since $e$ is an epimorphism; and this in turn implies that $m$ factorizes as $\ker(d_n)m'$, and thus $\bar{d}_{n+1}=m'e$. Since $m$ is a kernel, $m'$ is also a kernel, and in particular it must be the kernel of its cokernel; and since $e$ is an epimorphism, we have
$$\operatorname{coker}(m')=\operatorname{coker}(m'e)=\operatorname{coker}(\bar{d}_{n+1})=H_nC=0.$$
Thus $m'$ is an isomorphism, which means that $\bar{d}_{n+1}=m'e$ is a cokernel.

Comment: Thank you. There is just one thing I can't understand. Why do $m'$ mono + $m'$ epi imply $m'$ iso?

Comment: It's not because $m'$ is a mono and an epi. It's because $m'$ is the kernel of its cokernel, and its cokernel is actually equal to $0$.

Comment: Got it. Now I can't understand: "since $m$ is a kernel, $m'$ is also a kernel"

Comment: Sorry, I got it now.